# Fastest way to update large amount of data

Tags: mongodb

I have milions of rows in mongo collection and need to update all of them.
I've written a mongo shell (JS) script like this:

```
db.Test.find().forEach(function(row) {
    // change data and db.Test.save()
});
```

which (i guess) should be faster then e.g. updating via any language driver due to possible latency between web server and mongo server itself and just because the fact, that driver is "*something on the top*" and mongo is "*something in the basement*".

Even though it can update aproximately **2 100 rec./sec** on quad-core 2.27GHz processor with 4GB RAM.

As i know **mongoimport** can handle around **40k rec./sec** (on the same machine), i don't think mentioned speed is anything "fast".

**Is there any faster way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible limiting factors here:

1. **Single write lock:** MongoDB only has one write lock, this may be the determining factor.
2. **Disk Access:** if data being updated is not actively in memory it will need to be loaded from disk which will cause a slow-down.

> Is there any faster way?

The answer here depends on the bottleneck. Try running `iostat` and `mongostat` to see where the bottleneck lies. If `iostat` shows high disk IO, then you're being held back by the disk. If `mongostat` shows a high "lock%" then you've maxed out access to the global write lock.

If you've maxed out IO, there is no simple code fix. If you've maxed out the write lock, there is no simple code fix. If neither of these is an issue, it may be worth trying another driver.

> As i know mongoimport can handle around 40k rec./sec (on the same machine)

This may not be a fair comparison, many people run `mongoimport` on a fresh database and the data is generally just loaded into RAM.

I would start by checking `iostat` / `mongostat`.

Comment: Here is mongostat: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z92Abh2L and here is iostat: http://pastebin.com/chaJF3L3 What is actually "high lock %"?

Comment: On `mongostat` your `locked %` is low, only about 17%. So it's not the database write lock. Usually I run `iostat -xkd 1` to get a 1 second interval for IO usage (with usage displayed in kB/s). A good server drive should be getting > 50 MB/s, so see if that's blocking. The step is then `top`. If you're not maxing out IO and you're not maxing out Mongo's write lock, then check the CPU. (only other bottle-neck I can see) The only other option is to write the update command as a "multi" update, but that's not always possible.